# Slackware fails to boot after installing inside qemu as guest in ubuntu

Tags: boot, ubuntu-16.04, linux-kvm, slackware

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 as host OS and I'm trying to install slackware as a guest OS.

I'm using QEMU/KVM as emulator.
I followed [this link](https://docs.slackware.com/slackware:install) to install slackware.
But after installation it asks to reboot, but after reboot the slackware isn't booting.

Slackware uses LILO as bootloader not GRUB.
I found [this link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/building-slackbuilds-kvm-doesn%27t-work-2-6-35-4-kernel-835647/) in forums about installing the slackware in KVM.
But I'm not able to get what the thread's conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Slackware uses LILO as bootloader not GRUB.

Slackware contains GRUB.
You can install it as boot loader immediate after setup:
https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:slackware_admin:grub_on_first_install

or sometime later.

Answer (score 0):

> but after reboot the slackware isn't booting.

What you see at boot? Any messages?